# Cannot run Strapi with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, strapi

I'm trying to Dockerize my `Strapi` application, so first all in the root directory of the project I have created an `.env` file which contains the following:

```
HOST=0.0.0.0
PORT=3002
```

then, inside `backend/config/server.js` I have:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  host: env("HOST", "0.0.0.0"),
  port: env.int("PORT"),
  admin: {
    auth: {
      secret: env("ADMIN_JWT_SECRET", "3b8efb990e54568fc0d91ff31390cda7"),
    },
  },
});
```

this code is supposed to bind the application to `0.0.0.0`. Infact, when I run the container I can see that is binded to `0.0.0.0`.

After this, I have created a `Dockerfile` which contains the following instructions:

```
FROM node:12

EXPOSE 3002

WORKDIR /backend

COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

RUN ls -l

CMD ["npm", "run", "develop"]
```

then I have a `docker-compose.yml` that has:

```
version: '3'
services:
  backend:
    container_name: foo_backend
    build: ./backend/
    ports:
      - '3002:3002'
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/usr/src/foo/backend
      - /usr/src/foo/backend/node_modules
    environment:
      - APP_NAME=foo_backend
      - DATABASE_CLIENT=mysql
      - DATABASE_HOST=foo_mysql
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
      - DATABASE_NAME=foo_db
      - DATABASE_USERNAME=foo
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=foofoo
      - DATABASE_SSL=false
      - DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_DATABASE=foo_db
      - HOST=localhost
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: always
```

(I didn't added here the `db` service).

When I run the container using `docker-compose up --build` everything works well in the log:

[image]

but when I visit `http://localhost:3002` I get:

> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

This only happen on windows. Any idea?

**NGINX CONFIGURATION**

```
server {
        server_name mysite.backend.domain.com www.mysite.backend.domain.com;

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3002/;
        }

}
```

this is the error that I get:

> [error] 6783#6783: *82 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 93.148.94.171, server: mysite.backend.domain.com request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3002/favicon.ico", host: "mysite.backend.domain.com", referrer: "https://mysite.backend.domain.com/"

Comment: File line endings when mounting files from Windows into natively Linux programs can cause some very strange issues. 

Not certain this is in play here, but worth noting.

Comment: @ArthurWeborg just noticed now that is not working even on linux, infact nginx return as log: `upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, for large requests`, this means that for somereason nodejs is closing the connection

Comment: definitely useful information -- might be worthwhile to remove windows from title

Comment: Can you curl the service from within your running container? `docker exec -it <container-running-backend> bash`  and then do a `curl localhost:3002`? does it also produce  a similar result?

Comment: @ArthurWeborg great tips! seems like return the html with the login page, so actually seems that the container is running correctly. Why does nginx return 502? I will update the question with the nginx config

Comment: happy to be of assistance. This is useful information too! :) Do you have nginx running on your host machine?

Comment: @ArthurWeborg yes, I have a DigitalOcean cluster. I have added the configuration of nginx in the question. The same configuration works for the other application "frontend" maded by Gatsby in React

Comment: Ah I see, so your cluster is using nginx as an ingress proxy and is forwarding requests to respective host ports? Does accessing things via `mysite.backend.domain.com` take you to your strapi login page?

Comment: Also, is your service on the same node of the cluster that is running your strapi service?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227094/discussion-between-sfarzoso-and-arthur-weborg).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are doing a little mistake here, in environment variables of backend service replace - `HOST=localhost` to - `HOST=0.0.0.0`
It will work.

Comment: This causes issues with Google Auth provider. https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/726. I'm currently trying to test this in localhost.